# Derivation Of Euler-Lagrange Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

I want the proof of this relation in details,

$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left(\frac{\partial\vec{r}_v}{\partial q_\alpha}\right)=\frac{\partial\vec{\dot{r}_v}}{\partial q_\alpha}
$$

Comment: Hint: partial derivatives of $C^2$ functions commute.

Comment: Well what about the application of the derivatives do you not understand?

Comment: i cannot understand the demonstration of this relation

Comment: I don't have my copies with me but I suspect Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics* or any other collegiate intermediate mechanics text will detail this.

Answer (score 2):

Here it should be paid attention that time derivative is not a partial derivative. We can't from the start say that derivatives commute. However it turns out to be so after expressing time derivative in terms of partial derivatives since
 $$
\vec{v}_i=\frac{d\vec{r}_i}{dt}=\sum_k \frac{\partial\vec{r}_i}{\partial q_k}\dot q_k+\frac{\partial\vec{r}_i}{\partial t}
 $$
Remembering that $\frac{\partial{\dot q}_i}{\partial q_k}=0$ you can show that total time derivative commutes with derivation w.r.t $q$.

Comment: thnx everyone, i will post my try tomorrow